# Update ASP.NET Core site with Kestrel Server

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have configured reverse proxy to kestrel with nginx. When I redeploy the new DLLs using a bash script the site is not getting updated. I can see only the old site. When I try to kill dotnet process also it doesn't work. Even I tried restarting nginx, still no luck. I have to restart the server(linux) to see the changes. Why is it happening?

I want kestrel to detect changes when I update the files and automatically restart itself (or do something to publish the new site). Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: When you change dll files, you definitely have to restart the dotnet process  to pick up the changes. How are you controlling the dotnet process?

Comment: @natemcmaster I tried to kill the dotnet process using kill command. The process restarts with a different PID, but the site is not updated.